# thread problem in suspend() and resume()

Tags: java, android

hi all
i doing a stop watch. for pause i use Thread.suspend() and resume i use Thread.resume(). but the resume is not resume the work.
code:

```
pause(){
  shouldRun = false; 
  currentThread.suspend();      
}
resume(){
  shouldRun = true; 
  currentThread.resume();  
}
```

while(shouldRun){
    .......
  }

Comment: currentThread != the current thread?

Comment: if (currentThread==Thread.currentThread()) the resume would never execute, which i assume was given by the question. Maybe murali_ma can add a System.out.println(...) to each method and show the output.

Comment: Best answer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a reason why `Thread.suspend()` and `Thread.resume()` are deprecated - they're not a good idea for various reasons. Most importantly, the thread itself is in the best position to know how to pause *safely* (e.g. while not holding a lock).

I urge you to reconsider your design to avoid using suspend/resume. If you tell us more about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: For more information on why these methods are deprecated, you can read [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: hi i use Thread.wait() and Thread.notify() and notify() gives exception as object is not locked by thread before notify(). how to lock? i call notify() after wait().

Comment: @murali: You lock using the `synchronized` keyword. The current thread needs to own the lock on the object you call `wait` or `notify` on.

Comment: sorry i do not know  how to use synchronized. please give example related my problem.

Comment: @murali: I can't teach you about Java threading in comments on a question. I strongly advise you to find some good Java threading tutorials which will cover it in depth.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to suspend a Thread for some time have al look at java synchroniziation and especially Object.wait() and Object.notify/notifyAll()

Comment: hi i use Thread.wait() and Thread.notify() and notify() gives exception as object is not locked by thread before notify(). how to lock? i call notify() after wait().

Answer (score 1):

I dont't really get why you are using Thread.suspend() and resume for a stopwatch application.

Why don't you just get System.currentTimeMillis() each time the user presses the stopwatch button and compute the time delta?

Comment: hi i use Thread.wait() and Thread.notify() and notify() gives exception as object is not locked by thread before notify(). how to lock? i call notify() after wait().

Answer (score 0):

Google says an application should react in 100 or 200 ms : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html

You should use [Thread.Sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) function in your thread like that:
public void run(){
  do{
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    if(shouldRun){
      doSomething();  //do update your clockwatch
    }
  while(contidions);
}

Beware not doing any UI updates directly in a worker thread : 
Use and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to send your UI updates to the main thread : just UI updates functions.